# position a div relative to another not nested div

Tags: css, position

I can not change the html, I have 2 divs that are not nested, and I want to position div1 relative to div2 as they were nested. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: We will need to see some code. Please post your HTML structure and what you've already tried.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: this is the page, and I want the side menu to appear allways in the same place, try add to chart button, you see if the chart section in top have info, the menu also changes position.

Comment: sorry, the link: http://www.muscarici.ro/wp/?wpsc_product_category=bete

Answer (score 0):

```
var top = $('#firstElement').offset().top();
var left = $('#firstElement').offset().left();

top += relativeY;
left += relativeX;

$('#secondElement').css({'top': top; 'left': left});
```